# Force system cursor usage in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Let's say that you're using some black box library (i.e. no source code) that sets your cursor to something when rolling over a certain sprite. You can override that by catching rollOver and rollOut events, blocking propagation and using the CursorManager.

**Question**: is there a way to tell the CursorManager to use the system cursor?

Obviously, I could feed the CursorManager some "system like" cursor, but this would look weird if the local settings are different from that icon, which is likely to be always.

thank you!

f

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own version of `CursorManager` - just create file `mx/managers/CursorManager.as`, copy it's content from default manager (use `Ctrl+Shift+T` to navigate to it) and change the code.

If you use RSLs then you need to create [monkey-patch and load it BEFORE RSLs](http://blogs.adobe.com/dloverin/2010/01/how_to_monkey_patch_when_using_flex_rsls.html).

if you embed SDK into code then you can simply compile the app and class will be replaced.

Comment: Maxim, thanks for the tip on how create my own CursorManager class. The issue still holds - how do I programmatically tell Flex to display the system cursor (from inside my new class)?